# When human interpret a sentence, does syntactic analysis take place before any semantic analysis?

Tags: linguistics, psycholinguistics

When interpreting a sentence, does syntactic analysis take place before any semantic analysis?

Comment: it would be great if you can provide some initial research about this.

Comment: Also, do you mean reading or listening?